# Merge multiple cell data into single cell without losing data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

excel data
[image]

Need output like
[image]

I tried to merge in excel sheet but it showing error "merging cells only keeps the upper-left value and discards other values"

Comment: Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2209)

Comment: Please share the code you have tried. The message showing is not an error, it's an alert. You can get rid of it by simply wrapping the merge line into disabling and reenabling the display of alerts: `Application.DisplayAlerts = False: rg.Merge: Application.DisplayAlerts = True`. Or if you use `Select` (not recommended) then instead of `rg.Merge`, the line will be `Selection.Merge`.

Answer (score 2):

Something along the lines of:

[image]

Formula in `A8`:

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(A1:A6),IF({1,0},x,BYROW(x,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,FILTER(B1:B6,A1:A6=a))))))
```

Or:

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(A1:A6),HSTACK(x,BYROW(x,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),,FILTER(B1:B6,A1:A6=a))))))
```

Comment: Hi @JvdV fare value is printing one after another

Comment: I'm getting output like                                                                                              
CINEMA 101102103
TOUR 104105
BUS         106107

Comment: @VijayG.N, see [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/wrap-text-in-a-cell-2a18cff5-ccc1-4bce-95e4-f0d4f3ff4e84)

Comment: Thank you @JvdV  now I'm getting expected output.